# searching multiple files in sublime text?

Tags: grep, sublimetext

I'm trying to locate every instance of an expression in an open source project. Sublime text lets me do a search within a file for an expression like this with command F (on a Mac)

```
socket.on('api:admin.user.makeAdmin..
```

and SublimeText also lets me search for the *names* of `files` in the project but I don't know how to search multiple files for an expression that might occur anywhere. Since, for example, a socket can be listening for an `emit` anywhere in a project, it's hard to track down where the listeners are. However, this question obviously applies to more situations than that one example. If I can't do it with SublimeText is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `Find In Files`. Activate it with `ctrl` + `shift` + `F`.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime also has Find In Files where you specify a directory and can include subdirectories as well.
So for Find you type in the text you are looking for.  In Where you select the root project folder, then it will search all subfolders and files for your string entered in Find.  There is also a Replace entry which you can use as well.